# Batch convert text files to Excel .xlsx and convert text to columns using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, text

I have below program to batch convert text to excel (xlsx)

```
Sub LoopAllFiles()

    Dim sPath As String, sDir As String

    sPath = "C:\Users\DNA\Desktop\Test Convert\"

    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"

    sDir = Dir$(sPath & "*.txt", vbNormal)
    Do Until Len(sDir) = 0
        Workbooks.Open (sPath & sDir)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs Filename:=Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")) & "xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close
        End With

        sDir = Dir$
    Loop

End Sub
```

However, I have problem to convert text to columns using pipe delimiter. I have developed some syntax as per below but I am not sure how to combine it with the converter scripts.

```
Selection.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _ TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierNone, Other:=True, _
OtherChar:="|", FieldInfo:=xlTextFormat
```

May you all please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `OpenText` instead of `Open`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/office/ff837097.aspx) for the detailed reference.

```
Workbooks.OpenText filename:=sPath & sDir, dataType:=xlDelimited, tab:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
Sub LoopAllFiles()
    Dim sPath As String, sDir As String
    sPath = "C:\work\"
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"
    sDir = Dir$(sPath & "*.txt", vbNormal)
    Do Until Len(sDir) = 0
        Workbooks.Open (sPath & sDir)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
                :="|", FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            .SaveAs Filename:=Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")) & "xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close
        End With
        sDir = Dir$
    Loop
End Sub
```